# Sending images through Laravel Guzzle Client

Tags: laravel, file-upload, guzzle

I am trying to upload multiple images using guzzlehttp client. I load images as a file and loads only one image with the code below.

```
$clientPAimages = new Client();
$imagesPA = Req::file('images');
foreach($imagesPA as $image){
    $bodyImages[] = [
        'name'         => 'image',
        'contents'     => fopen($image->getRealPath(), 'r'),
        'filename' => $image->getClientOriginalName(),
        'headers'  => [
             'Content-Type' => '<Content-type header>'
        ]
    ];
}
               
$responsePA3 = $clientPAimages->request('POST', 'link/images', [
    'multipart' => $bodyImages
]);
$responsePA3->getBody();
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this i.e. how to save multiple images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in this kind of situation, when i needed to send multiple images from the laravel app to the node.js app. Your code seems ok, but may you've something wrong in your blade, for example usage of enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form, or name="images[]" as an input property, or something like that.

Anyway i'll share here the snippet, which worked well for me before, so i guess it can be useful.

Specifications for this snippet was:

- "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
- "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",

**create.blade.php**

```
<form action="http://internal.site/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input id="ss_images"
           name="images[]"
           type="file"
           multiple="multiple"
           class="input"
           accept=".jpeg,.bmp,.png,.jpg,.gif"
    />
    <div class="mt-3">
        <label class="{{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {{ $errors->has('name') ? $errors->first('name') : "Name" }}
        </label>
        <input value="{{ old('name') }}" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <label class="{{ $errors->has('description') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {{ $errors->has('description') ? $errors->first('description') : "Description" }}
        </label>
        <textarea class="input" placeholder="Description" name="description">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ItemController.php**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// ...

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only([
        'name',
        'description',
    ]);

    $multipart = [];
    if($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $k => $image) {
            $multipart[] = [
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => fopen($image->getRealPath(), 'r'),
                // ... some additional fields
            ];
        }
    }

    // adding some text-oriented data if need
    $multipart[] =  [
        'name' => 'data',
        'contents' => json_encode($data, true),
    ];

    $client = new Client();
    $url = "http://external.site/link/images";
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'multipart' => $multipart
    ]);

    $res_json = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $res = json_decode($res_json, true);

    return redirect()->back()->with([
        'success' => $res['success'],
        'flash_message' => $res['message'],
    ]);
}
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code works, but I have a problem I saw after your answer. However, the api service through which I have to send images,
can send only one image. Which means I need to call a request as many times as I have images.

Comment: if you're printing the $request->hasFile('images'); in the first line of your method and getting just one file, it means something went wrong with your front-end. please just pay attention about what i've written about the front-end

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag, and name="images[]" in the input tag

Comment: or maybe you're using another front-end architecture, so the reason comes from there

Comment: check using dd()'s how many file you get, then you can even using facade class of guzzle or loop through to add more array elements as per the amount of images in the request

Comment: yes, when you'll be sure that the front gives you multiple images, then please dd($multipart); before $response = $client->request(...); did you get multiple images there, and make sure that you've set guzzle's client argument right

Comment: @boolfalse I fixed it by calling the request in the foreach loop. Anyway, your code helped me.

Comment: nice to hear that.. thank you too